# Apache server easy URL navigation

Tags: url, apache2

this may be an easy question for you pros.

how can I make apache server automatically navigate to folder by doing this for example:

phpmyadmin works like this when I type localhost/phpmyadmin it shows me login page of phpmyadmin but in my FTP there is no folder phpmyadmin so the server just know where to redirect and my question is how can I achieve this.

Thanks for all answers in advance

Comment: Check out this link it's the Apache http server official documentation [apache 2.2 doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I wanted :)